# Elementor redirect on failed login

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, elementor

this is my first question on Stack Overflow

With the Elementor login widget when a user enters wrong or empty credentials, by default she is redirected to the wp-login.php page which is sub-ideal.

I found this workaround which does what I need but only partially: it reloads the current page appending ?login=failed to the URL. This works if one is using a login page.

In my case, however, the login can be from any page from a modal window.
It's hard to reload a modal.

I'd be happy if I could redirect to my-domain.com/login/?redirect_to=[referrer]

This is the code I am using now. Source: https://wordpressflow.com/elementor-on-failed-logins-on-the-login-form-redirect-back-to-the-login-page-and-add-a-failed-message/

Would anyone know how to amend it to redirect to my-domain.com/login/?redirect_to=[referrer] ?
Thanks

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'elementor_form_login_fail', 9999999 );
function elementor_form_login_fail( $username ) {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
    // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
    if ((!empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') )) {
        //redirect back to the referrer page, appending the login=failed parameter and removing any previous query strings
        //maybe could be smarter here and parse/rebuild the query strings from the referrer if they are important
        wp_redirect(preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $referrer) . '?login=failed' );
        exit;
    }
}
// This is also important. Make sure that the redirect still runs if the username and/or password are empty.
add_action( 'wp_authenticate', 'elementor_form_login_empty', 1, 2 );
function elementor_form_login_empty( $username, $pwd ) {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
 if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $pwd ) ) {
    if ((!strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') )) {
        //redirect back to the referrer page, appending the login=failed parameter and removing any previous query strings
        //maybe could be smarter here and parse/rebuild the query strings from the referrer if they are important
        wp_redirect(preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $referrer) . '?login=failed' );
        exit;
    }
   exit();
 }
}
```